# In R, make a conditional indicator variable based on (a) the first instance of a record type and (b) a date difference

Tags: r, date, dplyr

**Background**

Here's a `df` with some data in it from a Costco-like members-only big-box store:

```
d <- data.frame(ID = c("a","a","b","c","c","d"), 
                purchase_type = c("grocery","grocery",NA,"auto","grocery",NA), 
                date_joined = as.Date(c("2014-01-01","2014-01-01","2013-04-30","2009-03-08","2009-03-08","2015-03-04")),
                date_purchase = as.Date(c("2014-04-30","2016-07-08","2013-06-29","2015-04-07","2017-09-10","2017-03-10")),
                stringsAsFactors=T) 

d <- d %>%
  mutate(date_diff = d$date_purchase - d$date_joined)
```

This yields the following table:

[image: what_i_got]

As you can see, it's got a member `ID`, purchase types based on the broad category of what people bought, and two dates: the date the member originally became a member, and the date of a given purchase. I've also made a variable `date_diff` to tally the time between a given purchase and the beginning of membership.

**The Problem**

I'd like to make a new variable `early_shopper` that's marked `1` on *all* of a member's purchases if

1. That member's **first** purchase was made within a year of joining (so `date_diff <= 365` days).
2. This first purchase *doesn't* have an `NA` in `purchase_type`.

If these criteria aren't met, give a 0.

What I'm looking for is a table that looks like this:

[image: what_i_want]

Note that Member `a` is the only "true" `early_shopper`: their first purchase is non-`NA` in `purchase_type`, and only 119 days passed between their joining the store and making a purchase there. Member `b` looks like they could be based on my `date_diff` criterion, but since they don't have a non-`NA` value in `purchase_type`, they don't count as an `early_shopper`.

**What I've Tried**

So far, I've tried using `mutate` and `first` functions like this:

```
d <- d %>%
  mutate(early_shopper = if_else(!is.na(first(purchase_type,order_by = date_joined)) & date_diff < 365, 1, 0))
```

Which gives me this:

[image: attempt_1]

Something's kinda working here, but not fully. As you can see, I get the correct `early_shopper = 1` in Member `a`'s first purchase, but not their second. I also get a false positive with member `b`, who's marked as an `early_shopper` when I don't want them to be (because their `purchase_type` is `NA)`.

Any ideas? I can further clarify if need be. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my approach using a join to get the `early_shopper` value to be the same for all rows of the same ID.

```
library(dplyr)
d <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L), 
                               .Label = c("a","b", "c", "d"), 
                               class = "factor"), 
                purchase_type = structure(c(2L, 2L, NA, 1L, 2L, NA), 
                                          .Label = c("auto", "grocery"), 
                                          class = "factor"), 
                date_joined = structure(c(16071, 16071, 15825, 14311, 14311, 16498), 
                                        class = "Date"), 
                date_purchase = structure(c(16190, 16990, 15885, 16532, 17419, 17235), 
                                          class = "Date")), 
           class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

d %>%
  inner_join(d %>%
               mutate(date_diff = d$date_purchase - d$date_joined) %>%
               group_by(ID) %>%
               slice_min(date_diff) %>%
               transmute(early_shopper = if_else(!is.na(first(purchase_type,
                                                              order_by = date_joined)) & 
                                                  date_diff < 365, 1, 0)) %>%
               ungroup()
             )

  ID purchase_type date_joined date_purchase early_shopper
1  a       grocery  2014-01-01    2014-04-30             1
2  a       grocery  2014-01-01    2016-07-08             1
3  b          <NA>  2013-04-30    2013-06-29             0
4  c          auto  2009-03-08    2015-04-07             0
5  c       grocery  2009-03-08    2017-09-10             0
6  d          <NA>  2015-03-04    2017-03-10             0
```

Comment: A fine solution. I like the self joining combined with `transmute`.

Comment: This works terrifically, Ben, thanks so much. The real dataset this will be applied to is quite large (200m x 20, or thereabouts), so I'm going to see how quickly it runs on the real thing compared to Martin's above.

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```r
library(dplyr)

d %>%
  mutate(date_diff = date_purchase - date_joined) %>% 
  group_by(ID, purchase_type) %>% 
  arrange(ID, date_joined) %>% 
  mutate(
    early_shopper = +(!is.na(first(purchase_type)) & date_diff <= 365)
    ) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(early_shopper = max(early_shopper)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

which returns

```r
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  ID    purchase_type date_joined date_purchase date_diff early_shopper
  <fct> <fct>         <date>      <date>        <drtn>            <int>
1 a     grocery       2014-01-01  2014-04-30     119 days             1
2 a     grocery       2014-01-01  2016-07-08     919 days             1
3 b     NA            2013-04-30  2013-06-29      60 days             0
4 c     auto          2009-03-08  2015-04-07    2221 days             0
5 c     grocery       2009-03-08  2017-09-10    3108 days             0
6 d     NA            2015-03-04  2017-03-10     737 days             0
```

If you want the `early_shopper` column to be boolean/logical, just remove the `+`.

### Data

I used this data, here the `date_joined` for `b` is `2013-04-30` like shown in your images and not like in your actual data posted.

```r
structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("a", 
"b", "c", "d"), class = "factor"), purchase_type = structure(c(2L, 
2L, NA, 1L, 2L, NA), .Label = c("auto", "grocery"), class = "factor"), 
    date_joined = structure(c(16071, 16071, 15825, 14311, 14311, 
    16498), class = "Date"), date_purchase = structure(c(16190, 
    16990, 15885, 16532, 17419, 17235), class = "Date")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. What if I wanted all of an `early_shopper`'s records to be marked 1 -- i.e. have both of member A's purchases marked 1?

Comment: Changed my answer.

Comment: Thanks very much for this Martin, and sorry about the mismatch between screenshot and described `df` -- I've corrected the original post so I think everything's in line now. I'm going to see which of either yours or Ben's answers is quicker on my "real" dataset, which is quite large. But this is exactly the thing I'm looking for and can't thank you enough. 

Comment: If you use only `first` value of `date_diff`, you can avoid the last `group_by` i.e `early_shopper = +(!is.na(first(purchase_type)) & first(date_diff) <= 365)`